# How to reduce APK size in react-native with zoom SDK?

Tags: react-native, apk

I used zoom SDK in my react-native app. Zoom SDK size is 109MB.
Before I integrate zoom SDK, the size of APK was 25MB, but after I integrate zoom SDK, it increased up to 68MB. In addition, I have already modified some parts on the app/build.gradle, so APK was separated into 4 parts. In this case, how to reduce APK size?

> app / build.gradle

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true  //---> initial value was false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true          //---> initial value was false
```

Answer (score -2):

Try To update your android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig{
ndk {
           abiFilters "arm64-v8a"

}}
```

[image]